# Read data from TTY-emulating USB stick directly from kernel space

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a USB stick that sends data emulating the serial protocol using CDC.

Now I want to write a kernel driver that reads data from this USB stick and keeps the data in kernel space.

A small use-space program reading the data from /dev/ttyACM* does not solve the problem because I want to use the data from the USB stick directly in the kernel space.

Comment: You can a) write a driver that will connect to the tty node; b) rewrite ACM driver; c) extend ACM driver; d) take data by application in user space and send it back to another driver in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

you should enable Usb gadget feature in kenrel configuration, after instering usb stick, "lsusb" to check usb device tree status. If the endpoint description is a Serail type device normally, I think it should work.
you also can use libusb library to access your usb device